# using variable as part of the statement

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.4

I want to use a variable as part of the statement, but it says that "tableref" doesn't exist.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ff(tipo_acta integer, hasta date)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
 tableref varchar;
 r record;
BEGIN
 if tipo_acta = 1 then
          tableref = 't1';
 elsif tipo_acta = 2 then tableref = 't2';
 else tableref = 't3';
end if;

for r select id from tableref where somedate >= hasta loop
--
end loop;
```

I tried to use `EXECUTE 'select id from ' || tableref || ' where....'`  but doesn't work either

I thought to get the record first with `select id into r from t1 where ..` and then use it in the loop, but there seems to be no way to use a record in a loop like that:

```
FOR r LOOP
....
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dynamic sql for that. You need to use [`execute` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to do that in PLPG/SQL.

In your code it should be something like:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT id FROM ' || tableref || ' WHERE somedate >= $1'
INTO c
USING hasta;
```

Comment: thanks, I was in the right path after all
`FOR r IN EXECUTE ... LOOP`